# Extract .tar.gz file on Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, gzip, tar

I am not able to extract the file named hadoop-3.1.0.tar.gz on Windows 10. How can I get it done?

I have tried using the command :

```
tar -xvzf C:\Users\sheno\Downloads\hadoop-3.1.1.tar.gz -C C:\Users\sheno\Downloads\hadoop-3.1.1.tar.gz
```

The error that I am getting is :

```
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'C:\Users\sheno\Downloads\hadoop-3.1.1.tar.gz'
```

There is no other way that has worked out in extracting the files

Comment: Typo? "the file named hadoop-3.1.0.tar.gz" doesn't exist as part of the code in question. 3.1.1 failed to open because it doesn't exist?

Comment: Also, you should remove the `-C` option and it's argument

Comment: Generally, your syntax seems to be pretty correct to the T of full tar command definition, apart from what guys already mentioned that you probably had a typo in the filename so such a file didn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tar` is a Linux archive utility.  7-zip, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484133/whats-a-good-tar-utility-for-windows), will unpack that tarball.

As cricket_007 points out, 39 years after AT&T Bell Labs compiled tar, Microsoft used someone else's code to include tar/curl with Windows 10.

Comment: You sure about that? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/